# Searching for data using subqueries in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

i have 2 tables

```
Table A
columns - id1(number), id2(alpha-numeric), createdOn(date), modifiedOn(date)
example data - id1 1043568, dfd43585-hfj653, any date, any date
               id1 10438, dfd485-hfj653, any date, any date
               id1 14568, dfd43585-hfj653, any date, any date

Table B
columns - id3, isValid
ex: id3 - 1043568, isValid - 0
    id3 - 13568, isValid - 0
```

i have a query which fetches data based on input

```
select a.id1 as id, b.isValid as validity 
from A a 
join B b on a.id1=b.id3 
where a.id2 like '435';
```

output: id - 1043568, validity -0

what i want is the data where the a.id2 like 435 or a.id1 like 435
expected output:

```
id - 1043568, validity - 0; id - dfd43585-hfj653, any date
```

what i wrote is

```
select a.id1 as id, b.isValid as validity 
from A a 
join B b on a.id1=b.id3 
where a.id2 like '435' or a.id1 like '435';
```

but the query i wrote is not working. expected output is it should search for id1 & id3 (common in 2 tables) and also just the id2 from first table. maybe i need a subquery?

Comment: Use `=` when you're comparing with a fixed string. `LIKE` is for pattern matching.

Comment: *`where a.id2 like '435'`* is the same as `where a.id2 = '435'`. The pattern should contain wildcards: `where a.id2 like '%435%'`

Comment: You can't be getting that result with your first query.

Comment: @Akina Yes,  I want pattern matching, can someone write the query here.